# Restrict exposing certain request headers for REST API in browser

Tags: rest, api, google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-devtools

I am fetching a **GET** API using the `fetch` command in react. When I run the production build, I can see the `x-api-key` in request header when I inspect in either Google/Firefox (network). This is the API key that my web app uses to make the request and I don't want it to get exposed in the browser's devtools. Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fundamentally, you rewrite some stuff and proxy the request server side.

There is no way to hide the x-api-key header if you are directly making the request from the client. The *only* way is to make it from the server, then provide the results to the client.

Comment: I used a tokenizer on the back-end for my API instead of the `x-api-key`. Thanks!